# Is it possible to use a variable with self in Python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop, self

I want to make instance attributes for a class from a dictionary with a for loop. The code bellow shows what I am trying to accomplish. The code now only saves a attribute named "key" in the object and not "a, b, c"

The following code is for demonstration purpose.

```
class A:
    LIST= {'a' : 22 , 'b' : 13, 'c' : 11}

    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in in self.LIST.items():
            self.key = value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are requesting you can use `setattr` for this

```
class A:
    LIST= {'a' : 22 , 'b' : 13, 'c' : 11}

    def __init__(self):
        for key, value in self.LIST.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

You can then access these members like

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
22
>>> a.b
13
>>> a.c
11
```

Comment: if you're lazy, you could also just do `self.__dict__.update(self.LIST)`

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick